# Android Quadratic Equation, change double value from Edit text

Tags: android, equation, quadratic

can someone please help me, I am trying to do a simple quadratic equation app, and I can't figure out how to make the double variables get the value from the text inputed in the Edit text field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply take the string value from the EditText and parse it to a Double.

```
double value = Double.parseDouble(myEditText.getText().toString());
```

Comment: What am I doing wrong? the st1, st2 and st3 are the Edi texts

@Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    double a = Double.parseDouble(st1.getText().toString());
    double b = Double.parseDouble(st2.getText().toString());
    double c = Double.parseDouble(st3.getText().toString());
    dis = (b * b - 4 * a * c);
    d = Math.sqrt(dis);
    x1 = ((-b + d) / (2.0 * a));
    x2 = ((-b - d) / (2.0 * a));

Comment: @БориславМинчев That looks correct. What error do you get? Edit your question to include the error and relevant code.

Comment: Sorry, here is a better view, I am getting errors on st1, st2 and st3
[link](http://img266.imageshack.us/img266/7339/java1.png)

Comment: You haven't declared st1, st2 and st3 anywhere....

Comment: Like this? EditText st1, st2, st3;
because the app now crashed when I pressed the button to calculate

Comment: You also have to assign values to them, like you do to the button